# What options for the implementation of the insmod on the Linux kernel configuration?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I'm learning to try to make minimal Linux following the [tutorial](https://gist.github.com/chrisdone/02e165a0004be33734ac2334f215380e), I tried
load a module but I get an error like this:

```
/ $ insmod kdb.ko
insmod: can't insert 'kdb.ko': Function not implemented
/ $
```

I thought, when configuring the kernel I missed
something, knowledge of my kernel configuration is still minimal, does anyone know what options to get `insmod`
implemented?

**NOTE** : My configuration is done with the `alllnoconfig` option

Comment: Did you ensure the Kernel you are running supports loadable modules?

Comment: I tried before, when i try on qemu not working, my `.cpio` file can't load

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `allnoconfig`, `CONFIG_MODULES` will not be enabled. You need this config minimum to be enabled for `insmod` or `modprobbe` to work.

Comment: Thank's for answering :))